# Select Option in foreach only get value in last select option (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Why I can't post a select option value in foreach loop? It just save the last select option value.

It's only save the "Rutinitas" value in Printer (which is the last select option), but doesn't save the CPU or Mouse "Rutinitas" option value.

This is the controller

```
public function tampilkanKomponen2($tgl_cek,$nama_alat) {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_operator')) {
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_operator');
         $nip = $session_data['nip'];
         $nama = $session_data['username'];
        $hasil = $this->operator_model->getByAlat($nama_alat)->result();
        $hasil2 = $this->operator_model->showPengecekan()->result();    
        $data =array (
            'nip' => $nip,
            'nama' => $nama,
            'hasil2' => $hasil2,
            'hasil' => $hasil,
            //'hasil2' => $hasil2,
            'tgl_cek' => $tgl_cek,
            'nama_alat' => $nama_alat
            //'id_komponen2' =>$id_komponen
        );
        $this->load->view('tambah_pengecekan3_v',$data);
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> history.go(-1); </script>";
    }
}

public function simpanPengecekan() {
    if($this->operator_model->check_logged()==TRUE) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_operator');
        $nip = $session_data['nip'];
        $id_komponen = $this->input->post('id_komponen');
        $tgl_cek = $this->input->post('tgl_cek');
        $rutinitas = $this->input->post('rutinitas');
        $kriteria = $this->input->post('kriteria');
        $tindakan = $this->input->post('tindakan');
        $nama_alat = $this->input->post('nama_alat');

        $data =array (
            'id_komponen' => $id_komponen,
            'tgl_cek' => $tgl_cek,
            'rutinitas' => $rutinitas,
            'kriteria' => $kriteria,
            'tindakan' => $tindakan,
            'operator' => $nip
        );
        $hasil = $this->operator_model->tambahPengecekan($data);
        //redirect(base_url('operator'));
        $this->tampilkanKomponen2($tgl_cek,$nama_alat);
        //redirect_back();
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> history.go(-1); </script>";
    }
}
```

This is the view

```
<div class="container">
  <h4> Buat Pengecekan Baru </h4>
  <form method="post" action="simpanPengecekan">
  <div style="border-bottom : solid black 1px;margin-bottom:30px;">
    <div class="row row-form">
      <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label"> Tanggal Pengecekan </label> </div>
      <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" name="tgl_cek" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?php echo $tgl_cek; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-form">
      <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label">Nama Alat</label> </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" name="nama_alat" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nama_alat; ?>" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="../operator/tambahPengecekan"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Pilih Alat </button></a>
  </div>
      <h6>Komponen</h6>
      <?php $no=0;foreach($hasil as $row) { ?>
      <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="id_komponen" id="id<?php echo +$no;?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->id_komponen;?>" disabled>
          <p> <?php echo $row->nama_komponen;?> </p>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="javascript:showhide('pengecekan','<?php echo +$no;?>')"> Isi Pemeriksaan </button>      

          <div id="pengecekan<?php echo +$no;?>" style="display:none;">

        <div class="row row-form">
          <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label"> Rutinitas </label> </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
          <select name="rutinitas" class="form-control">
              <option value="Harian"> Harian </option>
              <option value="Mingguan"> Mingguan </option>
              <option value="Bulanan"> Bulanan </option>
              <option value="3 Bulanan"> 3 Bulanan </option>
              <option value="6 Bulanan"> 6 Bulanan </option>
              <option value="Tahunan"> Tahunan </option>
          </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-form">
          <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label"> Kriteria </label> </div>
          <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="kriteria"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-form">
          <div class="col-md-2"> <label class="control-label"> Tindakan </label> </div>
          <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tindakan"></div>
        </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Simpan"> <br><br><br>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php $no++; } ?>          
  </form>
      <br><a href="../operator"><button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-primary btn-batal">Selesai</button></a> <br> <br>
      <a href="../operator"><button type="button" class="btn btn-wide btn-default btn-batal">Batal</button></a>

</div>
```

---

**This is the model**

[image: THis is the model]

---

**THis is the result in database**

[image: This is the result in database]

Comment: It's because while you making a loop and the select control is inside so they are getting  **duplicate names**.  so it might be possible `rutinitas` has two times with same name so it won't post, make sure your select control has unique name. you can append something like `rutinitas_1` etc.

Comment: do you mean I should change the name of `rutinitas` become array like `rutinitas[]`? @RajJagani

Comment: if you have multi selected option than yes you can put name like`rutinitas[]` array but if you want to post a single value than you must have a unique name.

Comment: sir, i've changed the `rutinitas` to `rutinitas[]` and I put implode to my controller like this `$rutinitas = implode(',', $this->input->post('rutinitas'));`, but I got stuck, can you fix my code, please. @RajJagani

Comment: what error you are getting ?? and make sure in your database **rutinitas**  must have datatype of **text** or ** varchar** to store the comma seperated value

Answer (score 0):

Change select name to `rutinitas[]`

```
<select name="rutinitas[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="Harian"> Harian </option>
          <option value="Mingguan"> Mingguan </option>
          <option value="Bulanan"> Bulanan </option>
          <option value="3 Bulanan"> 3 Bulanan </option>
          <option value="6 Bulanan"> 6 Bulanan </option>
          <option value="Tahunan"> Tahunan </option>
      </select>
```

if you want to insert all selected value in same column of table then use `implode`

```
  $rutinitas = implode(',',$this->input->post('rutinitas'));
```

Comment: but when i try to change the name rutinitas to rutinitas[] it gets error. How to get value of each array? This is the error

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `tb_pengecekan` (`id_komponen`, `tgl_cek`, `rutinitas`, `kriteria`, `tindakan`, `operator`) VALUES ('87', '2016-06-07', Array, '', '', '789')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/kilatv2/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: it's because you can not directly store an array you can use ` implode(',',$this->input->post('rutinitas')) ` which makes you array to comma seperated value

Comment: sir, i still stuck at implode, how to use this? can you fix my code, please. @Vinie

Comment: in `simpanPengecekan()` change `$rutinitas =implode(',',$this->input->post('rutinitas'));`

Comment: then all selected value will be save in your db in this form `select1,select2,select3,`